# A problem when invoking a function in a bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

I've written the following bash script to find a driver's name, I'd make it better but for now I just want to know why this script doesn't work ?

```
#! /bin/bash

## the driver's name 
drivername=$(lspci -vv -s $(lspci |grep -i ethernet| awk -F" " '{print $1}')| awk -F" " '/driver/ {print $5}')

checkout ()
{
lsmod > tmp.txt
    if grep -i $1 "tmp.txt" > /dev/null ; then
        echo "there's a driver"
    else
        echo "there's not any driver"
    fi
}

ckeckout drivername ;
```

I've tested both of the following statements to make sure about invoking the function, but both of them didn't work.

```
checkout $drivername
```

and

```
checkout drivername
```

what's the problem with that ? So thanks.

Comment: how do you know they don't work?  What is the error or the actual problem?

Comment: @FrederickNord When I use something like this bash -x bash.sh or bash bash.sh It says that at the last line "the following command not found", got any ideas?

Comment: @user3679015 see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the corrected script:

```
#!/bin/bash

## the driver's name  
drivername=$(lspci -vv -s $(lspci |grep -i ethernet| awk -F" " '{print $1}')| awk -F" " '/driver/ {print $5}')

checkout () 
{ 
lsmod > tmp.txt
    if grep -i $drivername "tmp.txt" > /dev/null ; then
        echo "there's a driver called: $drivername"
        exit 0
    else
        echo "there's not any driver"
        exit 1
    fi 
}

checkout $drivername;
```

Comment: The problem is solved but why such the error was triggered ?

Comment: Because you made first of all a typo mistake: you wrote 'ckekout' instead of 'checkout', beside that you didn't referenced correctly the variable inside the function.